# Standard if(PeekMessage) else update&render-loop creates delay in message handling

Tags: c++, winapi

Following a Direct2D tuturial I've created a realtime update&render-loop like below. But when the update&render-loop takes long (eg when I have a `Sleep(5000)` somewhere in the `Update()`), normal messages handling like clicking the close window, can have to wait up to 5s.

So what is the proper way to split the message handling and realtime update&render-loop in two separate threads?

```cpp
while (message.message != WM_QUIT)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&message, windowHandle, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))   // check for events and pass them to WindowProc, otherwise
            DispatchMessage(&message);
        else                                                // run the realtime update&render loop
        {
            GameController::Update();
            graphics->BeginDraw();
            GameController::Render();
            graphics->EndDraw();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use a separate thread to perform expensive calculations on, and use the UI thread to display the results.

Comment: The pattern you need to implement is commonly called *Single Producer Single Consumer*. There are numerous implementations you can use, or implement your own for learning purposes.